# django migrate primary OneToOneFiled ForeignKey + into composite foreign key

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, migration

I've a model which is just a relation between two entities like this:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    a = OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True,...)
    b = ForeignKey(Car,...)
```

As per design, it was correct, as I didn't want an `User` to have multiple `Car`. But in my new design, I want to accept multiple `Car` to an `User`. So I was trying something like this:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("a", "b"),)
    a = ForeignKey(User,...)
    b = ForeignKey(Car,...)
```

But during migration, it asks me:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to somenmodel without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

**I just wanted to remove that foreign key from `OneToOneRelation` and add a new id combining both.** - How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the model and table from the database and create a new model from starting or add `null=True` to the given field. you must be having some data (rows) in your table and now you are creating a new column, so previous rows need something to be there in the newly created column, writing `null = True` will do that.

Comment: @Maifee you edited this answer, wasn't this helpful to you

Comment: I've edited the answer, and if you check the edition comment you get to see *I've added code as it should*... and for the answer... I'm still working on it... and not sure if it will help me in the future or not... only after a successful migration, I can tell... thanks... 
appreciate your contribution...